# css3 arrow on different system

Tags: html, css

I made two arrows, coded on MacOSX, I accidentally found the arrows don't look good on windows. Is that because of the resolution or the code is incorrect?

https://jsfiddle.net/m7ynysdp/

```
<div class="arrow a1"></div>
<div class="arrow a2"></div>

.arrow {
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    position: relative;
    color: #000;
}

.a1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 51%;
    left: 76%;
    transform: translate(-51%, -76%);
    width: 22vw;
    transform: rotate(-156deg);
    transform-origin: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
}

.a2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 53%;
    left: 65%;
    transform: translate(-53%, -65%);
    width: 6.5vw;
    transform: rotate(-111deg);
    transform-origin: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: color .3s;
}

.arrow::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -13px;
    right: -3px;
    content: '>';
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

First one is on mac, 2nd one is on Windows, both on Chrome latest version

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's off by a pixel for some reason. Changing the position to -> `top: -12px;` and adding a `font-weight: bold;` property seems to fix it.

```
.arrow::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    right: -3px;
    content: '>';
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oqfes3sk/

Perhaps you could add separate code for both Mac and PC after detecting the user agent:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mac') > 0){
  jQuery('body').addClass('mac');
 } else {
  jQuery("body").addClass("pc");
 }
});
```

and then:

```
.mac .arrow:before {

  ...
  top: -13px;

}

.pc .arrow:before {

  ...
  top: -12px;
  font-weight: bold;

}
```